# MySQL where/or ignores when match is not found

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following WHERE statement and when there are no matches for 22d22 the statement appears to ignore the next OR statement of uu111.  Is this default behavior?  How can I circumvent this?

```
WHERE (ListOfficeMLSID='549o' OR ListOfficeMLSID='22d22' OR ListOfficeMLSID='uu111') AND PhotoCount >= 1
```

Comment: no OR should check all.. May be the condition AND PhotoCount >= 1 along with ListOfficeMLSID='uu111' is resulting nothing. Try as just `where ListOfficeMLSID='uu111' AND PhotoCount >= 1 ` and see whatyou get.

Comment: Are you sure `PhotoCount` is good in that case. I cannot find better explanation

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `OR` between them. You can rewrite the where statement to this: `WHERE ListOfficeMLSID IN('549o','22d22','uu111') AND PhotoCount >= 1`

Comment: Double check your failed case directly with `WHERE ListOfficeMLSID='uu111' AND PhotoCount >= 1` and see what you get.  If you still have issues, create a simplified example and post it here with the full example data set, full example SQL statement, the results you get and the results you expected.  Enough that we can replicate it ourselves using www.sqlfiddle.com *(or, better still, create the example there for us to reference)*.

Comment: Please show your complete query, along with sample data and desired results.  I don't think your query is doing what you want it to.

Comment: @Arion is there a performance improvement with use of IN?  I am checking on the items everyone mentioned, I appreciate the help folks.